# Add variables to CodeIgniter email call

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have been trying to create variables to parse into the email class for sending mails in codeigniter. Assuming I want to send a mail to the logged in user, I decided to create a variable 
 
 `uemail = $_SESSION['email'];`
But then when I decided to parse it into the email class as `$this->email->to($uemail);`, does not send the email to the mail. But then when I use `$this->email->to('email@email.com');` the mail is sent to the email correctly so I'm thinking I'm experiencing problem with parsing the variable.  Doing `$this->email->to($_SESSION['email']);` too does not work. Please help me out. 
Thank you .

I just updated my question with detailed codes. I hope this helps. See below;

```
     <?php 
     $this->Sendmails_model->sendmail();
     $uemail = $_SESSION['email'];
     $this->email->to($uemail);
     $this->email->subject('Email subject here'); 
     $maildata = array(
       'firstName' => $_SESSION['first'],
       'content' => 'Email content here'
     );

  $body = $this->load->view('emails/basic',$maildata,TRUE);

  $this->email->message($body);

  $this->email->send();
?>
```

Comment: Can you paste more detailed code?

Comment: @AsoStrife Alright. Let me update my question with more details of the code.

Comment: I've tried your code but it work for me. 
What is `$this->Sendmails_model->sendmail();` ?

Comment: `$this->Sendmails_model->sendmail();` is a model where I have my email configuration.

Comment: @AsoStrife you were right. There is no problem with the code. There was issue with the server receiving the mail, hence never sent nor delivered.

Answer (score 1):

For setting session variables you have to use this syntax,

```
$this->session->userdata('session_variable');
```

Looking up the link in @Vickel 's comment, `$_SESSION['session_variable']` may also be used in CodeIgniter. Hence no problem with the codes.

From your comment, the issue was with the server receiving the email, hence we may consider this question solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bhavin. In most of my code, I parse session variables as `$_SESSION` and they worked perfectly. Just that it did not work with the email. Well I went ahead and still tried with your method `$this->session->userdata('session_variable');` but still no luck. My Session library is autoloaded. What do you think is causing this?

Comment: you may have a look at the updated question with the extra code.

Comment: have you tried to  with printing your session variable what is the result of  `echo $uemail` ? Because there may be a problem is that session is not properly setting in that variable.

Comment: Because if session is working and you are able to get the email address in `$uemail` than your code must work because it's working with static email address.

Comment: Yes, I was able to echo it. I think it may be because I can not find a way of putting quotes around the session variable. Because the email class works as $this->email->to('email@email.com');

Comment: But then parsing $_SESSION['email'] will make it `$this->email->to(email@email.com);` unlike setting a variable `$email = 'email@email.com'`

Comment: If you are getting variable in session variable than `$this->email->to($uemail);` will work try it. it will work because passing variable value doesn't need `' '`.

Comment: `In codeigniter you can't use $_SESSION. `is incorrect: from the docs: `Any piece of information from the session array is available through the $_SESSION superglobal:

$_SESSION['item']

` see: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Comment: @Bhavin can you please correct the first line of your answer?, see my earlier comment

Comment: @Bhavin your answer is correct just that the part about $SESSION is incorrect. Please correct that so I could mark your answer as correct. I realised it was the mail server for the email I was sending to that was not allowing delivery hence every other mail after it failed. Thank you so much.